# C# Awesomium выполнение скриптов

Tags: c#, awesomium

Есть сайт, на нем svg график. Надо сделать скриншот этой страницы. Но сам svg загружается чуть позже через socket и обработку js. Как с помощью Awesomium отработать все скрипты на странице?

Бо тут загружается только сам html.

```
while (webView.IsLoading)
        {
            WebCore.Update();
        }
```

Comment: Вставьте с помощью Awesomium на страницу скрипт, который будет мониторить состояние нужных элементов и, как только они будут загружены, выставлять некий флаг в `true`. А в C# запрашивайте значение этого флага.

Comment: С таким успехом я могу поставить `Sleep` на 10 секунд. И при этом все равно мне не загрузит